Next steps for QR-initiated Transactions in the fido protocol
When studying the FIDO2 protocol, I chose to use a pass key to log in without a password. At this time, the browser will pop up a QR code. By scanning the code, I can get a series of string information about FIDO:/+. For these 10 The hexadecimal string is decoded by go language to obtain data similar to this:
{0: h'037E2EF7C65FA68E15ED9B9A4CB72234CCCA8F9B84C76252D52796509B3188AB07', 1: h'49AA2EF2DE617E4CBA2AE2683D3CED08', 2: 2, 3: 1678113678, 4: true, 5: "mc", 6: true}

What I want to ask is what is the specific connection establishment and communication process between the mobile phone and the browser? How to analyze the specific data? Can a device be made to replace the QR code scanning login function of the iOS system?
This is the decoding step of the numeric string behind FIDO:/ in go language.
After CBOR decoding, we get:
{0: h'037E2EF7C65FA68E15ED9B9A4CB72234CCCA8F9B84C76252D52796509B3188AB07', 1: h'49AA2EF2DE617E4CBA2AE2683D3CED08', 2: 2, 3: 1678113678, 4: true, 5: "mc", 6: true}


The data encoded in the QR code is detailed in the latest version of the FIDO Client to Authenticator Protocol specification (§11.5.1).
In essence, the QR code represents a URI with FIDO:/ as its scheme, followed by a numeric string that can be decoded as a CBOR-encoded map with the following keys:


Key 0: a 33-byte, P-256, X9.62, compressed public key.
Key 1: a 16-byte random QR secret.
Key 2: the number of assigned tunnel server domains known to this implementation (see decodeTunnelServerDomain for details).
Key 3: (optional) the current time in epoch seconds.
Key 4: (optional) a boolean that is true if the device displaying the QR code can perform state-assisted transactions.
Key 5: either the string “ga” to hint that a getAssertion will follow, or “mc” to hint that a makeCredential will follow.
Implementations SHOULD treat unknown values as if they were “ga”. This
field exists so that guidance can be given to the user immediately
upon scanning the QR code, prior to the authenticator receiving any
CTAP message. While this hint SHOULD be as accurate as possible, it
does not constrain the subsequent CTAP messages that the platform may
send.



Thanks, I got it. But now I want to know the specific steps in the FIDO2 protocol after scanning the QR code through iOS, how the mobile phone and the browser establish a connection, and how the two communicate or how to know the specific data passed between them.

All of this is detailed in the linked specification.

Yeah, I have read this too, but I feel that some variable or method names are not described very clearly in the code of this article. And I don’t know much about Bluetooth, so I mainly want to know about the FIDO protocol Bluetooth communication.

"[...]  I feel that some variable or method names are not described very clearly in the code of this article [...]" It's not an article, it's the actual specification. Your question is becoming a little broad; it's not possible to explain the entire CTAP protocol, CaBLE protocol and Bluetooth protocol in a Stack Overflow answer.

Thank you for your patient reply, I will continue to look for information to solve the problem
